# Inference with Typescript, Observable and bindCallback method

Tags: typescript, types, rxjs, observable

I am writing a function in **nodejs** and **typescript** to search for certain patterns in a file.
The file is read line by line via the functions provided by the `readline` node package.

The code looks more or less like this

```
import * as readline from 'readline';
....
....
function _findSnippets(
    filePath: string,
    startSnippetToken: string,
    endSnippetToken: string,
    callback: (filePath: string, snippets: Array<Array<string>>) => void
) {
          // do some prep stuff
    const snippet = new Array<string>();
    const rl = readline.createInterface({
        input: fs.createReadStream(filePath),
        crlfDelay: Infinity
    });
    rl.on('line', (line: string)  => {
        let isLineToBeAddedToSnippet: boolean;
               // do the core of the logic to set the correct value for
               // the variable isLineToBeAddedToSnippet
        if (isLineToBeAddedToSnippet) {
             snippet.push(line);
        }
    })
    rl.on('close', ()  => {
        callback(filePath, snippet);
    })
}
```

I want to use the above defined function via the Observable pattern, so I use the `bindCallback` function of Observable to create an Observable that emits when the callback is executed.

The code to do the binding is the following

```
const _findSnippetsObs = Observable.bindCallback(_findSnippets);
```

Now I would like to see that Typescript via inference shows that the `_findSnippetsObs` function returns an Observable emitting some sort of "pair" of variables, i.e. the parameters of the callback which is the last parameter of the `_findSnippets` function. Rather, what I see via intellisense is that `_findSnippetsObs` returns an `Observable<string>` as you can see in this snapshot
[image]

In my opinion intellisense capabilities, specifically when it comes to async Observable based behaviors, are a very important tool.

Therefore I would appreciate if anybody can help me correct this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `bindCallback` method resolves to a call to `BoundCallbackObservable.create`, which has [numerous overloads](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/5.5.2/src/observable/BoundCallbackObservable.ts#L18-L34).

Your `_findSnippets` function takes three string parameters and a callback parameter, so the overloads that are relevant are these two:

```ts
static create<T, T2, T3, R>(
  callbackFunc: (v1: T, v2: T2, v3: T3, callback: (result: R) => any) => any,
  selector?: void,
  scheduler?: IScheduler
): (v1: T, v2: T2, v3: T3) => Observable<R>;

static create<T, T2, T3, R>(
  callbackFunc: (v1: T, v2: T2, v3: T3, callback: (...args: any[]) => any) => any,
  selector: (...args: any[]) => R,
  scheduler?: IScheduler
): (v1: T, v2: T2, v3: T3) => Observable<R>;
```

You've not specified a selector, so the first overload is matched - as excess parameters to the callback are ignored. The matching of that overload sees `R` inferred as `string`, which explains what you are seeing via intellisense.

For callbacks that receive more than one parameter, there needs to be some mechanism to package up the received arguments into something that can be emitted from an observable - that something could be an array or an object. To do that, you need to specify a selector. For example:

```ts
const _findSnippetsObs = Observable.bindCallback(
  _findSnippets,
  (filePath: string, snippets: Array<Array<string>>) => ({ filePath, snippets })
);
```

Here, specifying the selector will see the call match the second of the above overloads and the observable will emit objects with `filePath` and `snippets` properties.

Also, you might want to look at [`bindNodeCallback`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-bindNodeCallback) and consider adding a listener for `error` events - if they have the potential to be emitted by `readline`. Doing so would allow errors to be reported and handled using the observable stream.

Comment: First of all thanks for the answer. It works perfectly. Just to be sure I have understood the point about the inference, I want to ask you one more question: `R` gets inferred as `string` because the first input parameter of the callback of `_findSnippets` is a `string`. On the other hand, in the second case, `R` is the return value of the selector and therefore it gets the type of whatever the selector returns. Is this right?